# Set User Control's default event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, user-controls

I have a `User Control` containing a bunch of controls. I want to set the default Event of this `User Control` to the `Click` event of one of my buttons.

I know for setting default event to one of the UserControl's events I should add the attribute:

```
[DefaultEvent("Click")]
public partial class ucPersonSearch : UserControl
...
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to do something like:

```
[DefaultEvent("btn1_Click")]
public partial class ucPersonSearch : UserControl
...
```

I want to fire some methods in the form hosting this User Control at the time btn1 is clikced.

This is really a knit in my project, and you're answer will be valueable.

Comment: ??? I have no idea what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't expose events of your class members to the outside of the class. How can others subscribe to the `Click` event of a `Button` inside your `UserControl`? Did you try it? It's not possible unless you make the button accessible from the outside, which is not good (everybody can change all the properties).

You have to define a new event, and fire your new event when your desired event (clicking on the button) happens:

```
[DefaultEvent("MyClick")]
public partial class UCPersonSearch : UserControl
{
    Button btnSearch;
    public event EventHandler MyClick;

    public UCPersonSearch()
    {
        btnSearch = new Button();
        //...

        btnSearch.Click += new EventHandler(btnSearch_Click);
    }

    void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnMyClick();
    }

    protected virtual void OnMyClick()
    {
        var h = MyClick;
        if (h != null)
            h(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @MD.Unicorn good idea, before reading your answer the idea of making the button public came up, and it worked. Your answer is also good, even better. Good lock.

Comment: @MahdiTahsildari You're welcom, my compatriot :-)

Comment: Use `[DefaultEvent(nameof(MyClick))]` instead of hard-coding the name.

Comment: @jor Thanks for pointing that out, but the answer war written before C# 6 (2015) where this feature is introduced. :) For historical reasons, and sice the WinForms platform is no longer actively being used, I'll keep the answer that way.