# Public Custom Event on UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, event-handling

I want this:

```
public partial class ucTest : UserControl  
{
...  
SomeEvent { MessageBox.Show("Inner Call") }
}


public partial class frmTest: Form
{
...  
SomeEvent += OuterEventInstance;
...
void OuterEventInstance(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ MessageBox.Show("Inner Call") }
... 
}
```

How can I define a public event on a user control that is available (and expandable) in the form that contains an  instance of this user control?

Comment: What do you mean of "expandable"?

Comment: I mean this `SomeEvent += OuterEventInstance;` so that I can run some codes when the button inside user control gets clicked.

Comment: You need to explain more about your problem. I think you've got your answer on [my answer to your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14956801/1174942). The `MyClikc` event of your user control is accessible in its container form like other events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public partial class ucTest : UserControl  
{
   public event  EventHandler SomeEvent;

   private void OnSomeEvent()
   {
        EventHandler handler = SomeEvent;
        if(handler != null)
             handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
   } 

}


public partial class frmTest: Form
{
    public frmTest()
    {
        ucTest uc = new ucTest(); 
        uc.SomeEvent += OuterEventInstance;
    }

    //...

    void OuterEventInstance(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Inner Call")
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: @MahdiTahsildari What do you mean of "does not work"? In StackOverflow "does not work" does not work! :-)

Comment: @MahdiTahsildari Do you get a compiler error? Or you don't see the defined event int the events of the user control? Or you'll get an exception? Please clarify.

Comment: @MahdiTahsildari Does you invoke `OnSomeEvent` when the event raises in your user control?

Comment: Oops sorry it's OK. I had two very similar forms :) I was coding first and testing second one. What a shame :D thanks @MD.Unicorn & HamletHakobyan